# react-native facebook login using FBSDK login confirms without any permission page

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, fbsdk

I have added [gif here](https://giphy.com/gifs/QSYpjfMv5hth6)

is this the correct way of working because i have seen many login application through `facebook which asks for permission`

Sorry i have started recently working on `facebook api` and don't have sufficient knowledge on api

Facebook would login without prior asking of permissions and i have facebook lte app installed and i was logged in it.

Comment: Can you show your AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: @NaderDabit im working in android i don't know where do i find the file...?can you help me out

Comment: Ah, I assumed iOS. I have yet to work with the Facebook SDK using Android.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected. We try to skip the re-confirmation dialog if you've installed the Facebook app. To confirm you've logged in the app successfully. Please go to your Facebook on desktop, open setting https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications and make sure your app is listed.

Comment: but i was required to show that page which asks for user permission..how can i achieve that. Sorry for the delay